# Unity find canvas child and hide it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a screenshot script and when I take shot the whole canvas is being hidden. I just want to hide the camera button which is the child of the canvas and show it again after taking the screenshot. Here is my code.

```
IEnumerator CaptureIt()
{
    string timeStamp = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss");
    string fileName = "Screenshot" + timeStamp + ".png";
    string pathToSave = fileName;
    GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(pathToSave);
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = true;

    Instantiate (blink, new Vector2(0f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Comment: Pass in the object you're showing/hiding as a parameter or at the very least cache it, and then why can't you just `GameObject.Find("Screenshot Button")`?

Comment: I doesn't work either 
GameObject.Find("Screenshot").GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;

Comment: `GameObject.Find("Screenshot").SetActive(false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the child of a game object by its index.

You can use a code like this:

```
GameObject.Find("Canvas").transform.GetChild(index).gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

index: Index of the child transform between other children of a game object.

I do some changes in your code:

```
IEnumerator CaptureIt()
{
    string timeStamp = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss");
    string fileName = "Screenshot" + timeStamp + ".png";
    string pathToSave = fileName;
    GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<Canvas>().transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(false);
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    Application.CaptureScreenshot(pathToSave);
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<Canvas>().transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);

    Instantiate(blink, new Vector2(0f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

And you can use the function with this code `StartCoroutine(CaptureIt());`

It's a general answer.

But **especially for your question**, follow these steps:

- Create an empty Game Object
- Click on this empty game object and in Inspector, click on Add Component and create a new C# script

  [image]
- In the script, create 2 functions as below:

  ```
  public void Capture()
  {
       StartCoroutine(CaptureIt());
  }

  IEnumerator CaptureIt()
  {
      string timeStamp = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss");
      string fileName = "Screenshot" + timeStamp + ".png";
      string pathToSave = fileName;
      GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<Canvas>().transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(false);
      yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
      Application.CaptureScreenshot(pathToSave);
      yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
      GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<Canvas>().transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);

      Instantiate(blink, new Vector2(0f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
  }
  ```
- Now, in Hierarchy window, select your button and in Inspector window, in Button component click on Add to List and set your empty game object to this.

  [image]
- Finally, select Capture function to the button

  [image]

I hope it helps you

Comment: When I use the SetActive, the screenshot doesn't work and it just hide the button and didn't come back. maybe i need the enabled = false.

Comment: I added a sample code to my answer. it works for me. Hope helps you :)

Comment: yup i've tried it and i got the access of the Screenshot button but it hides the button and doesn't take screenshot. as you can see there is a WaitForEndOfFrame and I think what I need is enabled = false because I am accessing a component. setActive doesn't work well

Comment: also the Application.CaptureScreenshot(pathToSave); doesn't work for me is it because of that?

Comment: Do you add this script on your button and want to when clicking on the button, this button hide, then capture and finally show again? And `ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(pathToSave);` works for you?

Comment: Yes the script is added in the button. and Yes that is what I wanted to happen.

Comment: is there other way to hide the camera button?

Comment: Oh, I think we found the problem. if you add the script to your button, after you disable it, your script stopped. Because this game object disabled. One solution is to create a new game object and add your script to this. And when you click on the button, call the script from this game object.

Comment: Rather than index (which can change easily and unexpectedly), access it by name. `Transform#Find("path_and/name_of_child")`